# How to create an Android Quiz

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm planning to create an app for my classmates this Holiday So that we will be able to interact, share ideas, and challenge ourselves in a quiz.Like the SoloLearn app.

My Plan
-A user profile 
-Home page where users can share ideas with each other.
-A page where users can complete a quiz to test their knowledge. 
-The Challenge Zone where users can challenge each other in a quiz.
-.Settings 
1.where a user can log in /log out 
2.control the sound of the app.
3.switch to night mode and a search button to find other users.

But I don't even know where to start.

Have already download Java version 8, and Android Studio on my PC but I don't know the next step to take.

How do I achieve this goal?

Comment: Sorry but this question is too broad and opinion based, this is not the website for that kind of questions. You can ask this type of questions on [Softwarerecs on stack exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You have 2 separate IDEs tagged. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Lexi sorry about that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio)

Answer (score -2):

The best way is by learning the course and Moreover it is freely available at https://www.udacity.com/courses/android
Moreover they teach you from very basic level so just check it out i have tried it too

Answer (score -2):

if ever you want to create an app painlessly, consider app inventor from the MIT found [here](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/)